# How to create absolute and relative branches using gcc powerpc assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, powerpc

I am writing boot code where I would like to use only relative addressing with branch instructions.

I have noticed the following assembly code:

```
110: lwz r4,0(r6)
      ...
      ...
     b 110b
```

The destination of the branch is a label that is all numerics and the branch instruction has the letter 'b' after the label. I assume the 'b' means backwards. I have also seen 'f', which I assume means forward.

This notation would seem to imply relative addressing, but I can't find any documentation stating such.

Is the notation of using numerics followed by 'f' or 'b' the only mechanism to guarantee relative branching? or can an alphanumeric label (more meaningful names) be used with a f/b suffix?

I am using a gcc cross-compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative/absolute distinction is inferred from the instruction used. There should be no need for the assembler to guess which one you want. For PPC:

```
b  110b ; relative
ba 110b ; absolute
```

Comment: Thanks Igor. I missed the use of 'a' for absolute reading "Programming Environments Manual for 32-Bit Implementations of the PowerPC™ Architecture", my only PowerPC guide. It is obtuse in places.

Comment: Igor - Thank you for the reference. Lots of documentation. However, the documentation at 'the source' is very similar to the guide I cited. The tables are the same as is the notation. Both are reference guides targeted as writers of assemblers, not users. As reference guides they are very complete, but for a newbie to PowerPC assembly, not my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your other question is in the gas documentation on [Symbol Names](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html):

All-numeric labels are "local labels" and are used so you don't need to invent a unique name for each label; I imagine this is particularly useful inside macros. The b/f suffix is necessary to figure out which label you're referring to since the names don't need to be unique (it also tells the parser that it's a local label instead of an integer immediate).